# Magento:: How do i add a template to the print page using the local.xml

Tags: xml, magento

I'm trying to add a styleheet to the print pagina in Magento using the local.xml in the design folder.

I'm trying to print from the sales/order/detail page. I know this wont style the printed document but it will style the html document

Here's what i have in my local.xml:

```
 <print>
      <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addCss" name="global">
                <stylesheet>css/global.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </block>
      </block>
     </print>
```

That is what i pulled from the page.xml. This is whats in the base page.xml:

```html
<print translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages (Print Version)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Page -->
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/print.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

        </block>
    </print>
```

but all i get is a blank page. Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

It's right that you get a blank page, cause you're not updating what's inside a block/reference, but you're overriding it.

If you want to simply add an additional CSS file, you should do:

```xml
    <print translate="label" module="page">
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss" name="global">
                <stylesheet>css/global.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </print>
```

Otherwise you can copy and paste your second snippet, adding the line that will include the CSS file.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score -1):

You can see in the page.xml markup you pasted how to specify a print stylesheet: you need to specify the media attribute on your stylesheet to have the browser apply it in the print view. You also need to target the handle of the page you want to embed on `<sales_order_print>` or `<default>` for all pages, and the right block to add your new stylesheet to `<reference name="head">` in local.xml:

```
<sales_order_print>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet>
            <params>media="print"</params>
        </action>
    </reference>
</sales_order_print>
```